# Finding minimum and maximum on region

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find minimum and maximum values of $x+2y$, if $4x^2+y^2=3$.

I found $x_{max}=0.05$, $y_{max}=\sqrt{2.99}$. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write $2x=\sqrt3\cos\theta,y=\sqrt3\sin\theta$

$$x+2y=\dfrac{\sqrt3\cos\theta}2+2\sqrt3\sin\theta=\dfrac{\sqrt3}2\left(\cos\theta+4\sin\theta\right)$$

Now $\displaystyle a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos\left(\theta-\arctan\dfrac ba\right)$

and for real $\displaystyle\phi,-1\le\cos\phi\le1$

Comment: @LilyTurenko, Please pinpoint your confusion

Comment: @LilyTurenko, We don't need the maximum values of $x,y$ separately

Comment: @LilyTurenko, Here $a=?,b=?$

Answer (score 1):

If you know Lagrange multipliers, the problem is to find the extemum of $$F=x+2y+\lambda(4x^2+y^2-3)$$ Taking the partial derivatives $$F'_x=8 \lambda  x+1=0$$ $$F'_y=2 \lambda  y+2=0$$ $$F'_{\lambda}=4 x^2+y^2-3=0$$ Using the first two equations, you find that $y=8x$. So, solving the third equation (which is the constraint), you get two solutions corresponding to $$\left\{x\to \pm \frac{\sqrt{\frac{3}{17}}}{2},y\to \pm 4 \sqrt{\frac{3}{17}}\right\}$$ so the extreme values of $(x+2y)$ correspond to $$\pm \frac{\sqrt{51}}{2}$$